# pandas question: Remove missing values by column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe called teams. Each column is a team in the NFL, each row is how much a given fan would pay to attend a team's game. Looks like:

| team1 | team2 | team3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | NaN | 50 |
| NaN | NaN | 80 |
| 75 | 30 | NaN |

I want to compare the standard deviations of each column, so obviously I need to remove the NaNs. I want to do this column-wise though, so that I don't just remove all rows where one value is NaN because I'll lose a lot of data. What's the best way to do this? I have a lot of columns, otherwise I would just make a numpy array representing each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect.

> I want to compare the standard deviations of each column, **so obviously I need to remove the NaNs**

By default [`std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) ignores the `NaN` (`skipna=True`), so just use:

```
df.std()
```

Output:

```
team1    24.748737
team2          NaN
team3    21.213203
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`' .describe(), it shoul already account for any Nans:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['team1', 'team2',    'team3']
data = [
        [40, np.nan,    50],
        [np.nan, np.nan,    80],
        [75,    30, np.nan]]



df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
std = df.describe().loc['std']
```

**Output:**

```
print(std)
team1    24.748737
team2          NaN
team3    21.213203
```